# Checking in multiple files and associating same comment to single change set

Tags: rtc

Reading this doc http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v2r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/r_scm_cli_scm.html I check in a file using the command :

```
scm checkin myfile.txt
```

I need to check in multiple files and associate them with same change set (and comment) . How can I do this ? There does not seem to be any detail of how to associate file checkin with a comment or how to checkin multiple files as a single change set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple checkin should be added to the *same* change set, ie the one [`scm status`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v2r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/r_scm_cli_status.html) indicates as "active": '@'.

So if you create a change set first (`[`scm create --changeset`][2]`), the next checkins should be in that active changeset (use `scm changeset comment`  to update its comment).

Comment: is it possible to create a single changeset for multiple components in repository ?

Comment: @user470184 no: each change set is within a component in your Pending changes view. For one component, you can reuse a change set, but multiple components means multiple change sets.